# Apache Kafka Python - self.async

Tags: python-3.x, heroku, apache-kafka

I have configured Heroku-kafka version 3.8 and tried to create producer from the below code getting error as below , I have pasted my requirement.txt and my code

Please give me solution to resolve this issue.

```
    File "kafka-producer.py", line 5, in <module>
import kafka_helper
File "/app/kafka_helper.py", line 19, in <module>
from kafka import KafkaProducer, KafkaConsumer
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kafka/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
from kafka.producer import KafkaProducer
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kafka/producer/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
from .simple import SimpleProducer
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kafka/producer/simple.py", line 54
return '<SimpleProducer batch=%s>' % self.async
```

requirement.txt

```
Flask>=1.1.1
cffi==1.14.4
cryptography==3.2.1
enum34==1.1.10
ipaddress==1.0.23
kafka==1.3.5
kafka-helper==0.1
kafka-python==2.0.2
psycopg2==2.8.6
psycopg2-binary==2.8.6
pycparser==2.20
six==1.15.0
snowflake-connector-python==2.3.7
```

My Script

```
import snowflake.connector
import os
import json
import ssl
import kafka_helper
from kafka import KafkaProducer  # ,  KafkaConsumer
V_SSL_CONTEXT = kafka_helper.get_kafka_ssl_context().

# Create Producer Properties
def fn_kafka_producer(acks='all',
                      value_serializer=lambda v: json.dumps(v).encode('utf-8')):
    kafkaprod = KafkaProducer(
        bootstrap_servers=V_KAFKA_URL,
        # key_serializer=key_serializer,
        value_serializer=value_serializer,
        ssl_context=V_SSL_CONTEXT,
        acks=acks
    )
    return kafkaprod

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create the Producer
    PRODUCER = fn_kafka_producer()

    # Create a producer Record
    PRODUCER.send(KAFKA_TOPIC, 'Hello Heroku!!')
    PRODUCER.flush()
```

My Kafka_helper.py

```
""
```

Helper methods for creating the kafka-python KafkaProducer and KafkaConsumer objects.
"""

```
import os
import json
import ssl
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
try:
    from urllib.parse import urlparse
except ImportError:
    from urlparse import urlparse

from base64 import standard_b64encode

from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization

from kafka import KafkaProducer, KafkaConsumer


def get_kafka_ssl_context():
    """
    Returns an SSL context based on the certificate information in the Kafka config vars.
    """
    # NOTE: We assume that Kafka environment variables are present. If using
    # Apache Kafka on Heroku, they will be available in your app configuration.
    #
    # 1. Write the PEM certificates necessary for connecting to the Kafka brokers to physical
    # files.  The broker connection SSL certs are passed in environment/config variables and
    # the python and ssl libraries require them in physical files.  The public keys are written
    # to short lived NamedTemporaryFile files; the client key is encrypted before writing to
    # the short lived NamedTemporaryFile
    #
    # 2. Create and return an SSLContext for connecting to the Kafka brokers referencing the
    # PEM certificates written above
    #

    # stash the kafka certs in named temporary files for loading into SSLContext.  Initialize the
    # SSLContext inside the with so when it goes out of scope the files are removed which has them
    # existing for the shortest amount of time.  As extra caution password
    # protect/encrypt the client key
    
    with NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.crt') as cert_file, \
         NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.key') as key_file, \
         NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.crt') as trust_file:
        cert_file.write(os.environ['KAFKA_CLIENT_CERT'].encode('utf-8'))
        cert_file.flush()

        # setup cryptography to password encrypt/protect the client key so it's not in the clear on
        # the filesystem.  Use the generated password in the call to load_cert_chain
        passwd = standard_b64encode(os.urandom(33))
        private_key = serialization.load_pem_private_key(
            os.environ['KAFKA_CLIENT_CERT_KEY'].encode('utf-8'),
            password=None,
            backend=default_backend()
        )
        pem = private_key.private_bytes(
            encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,
            format=serialization.PrivateFormat.PKCS8,
            encryption_algorithm=serialization.BestAvailableEncryption(passwd)
        )
        key_file.write(pem)
        key_file.flush()

        trust_file.write(os.environ['KAFKA_TRUSTED_CERT'].encode('utf-8'))
        trust_file.flush()

        # create an SSLContext for passing into the kafka provider using the create_default_context
        # function which creates an SSLContext with protocol set to PROTOCOL_SSLv23, OP_NO_SSLv2,
        # and OP_NO_SSLv3 when purpose=SERVER_AUTH.
        ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context(
            purpose=ssl.Purpose.SERVER_AUTH, cafile=trust_file.name)
        ssl_context.load_cert_chain(cert_file.name, keyfile=key_file.name, password=passwd)

        # Intentionally disabling hostname checking.  The Kafka cluster runs in the cloud and Apache
        # Kafka on Heroku doesn't currently provide stable hostnames.  We're pinned to a specific certificate
        # for this connection even though the certificate doesn't include host information.  We rely
        # on the ca trust_cert for this purpose.
        ssl_context.check_hostname = False

    return ssl_context


def get_kafka_brokers():
    """
    Parses the KAKFA_URL and returns a list of hostname:port pairs in the format
    that kafka-python expects.
    """
    # NOTE: The Kafka environment variables need to be present. If using
    # Apache Kafka on Heroku, they will be available in your app configuration.
    if not os.environ.get('KAFKA_URL'):
        raise RuntimeError('The KAFKA_URL config variable is not set.')

    return ['{}:{}'.format(parsedUrl.hostname, parsedUrl.port) for parsedUrl in
            [urlparse(url) for url in os.environ.get('KAFKA_URL').split(',')]]


def get_kafka_producer(acks='all',
                       value_serializer=lambda v: json.dumps(v).encode('utf-8')):
    """
    Return a KafkaProducer that uses the SSLContext created with create_ssl_context.
    """

    producer = KafkaProducer(
        bootstrap_servers=get_kafka_brokers(),
        security_protocol='SSL',
        ssl_context=get_kafka_ssl_context(),
        value_serializer=value_serializer,
        acks=acks
    )

    return producer


def get_kafka_consumer(topic=None,
                       value_deserializer=lambda v: json.loads(v.decode('utf-8'))):
    """
    Return a KafkaConsumer that uses the SSLContext created with create_ssl_context.
    """

    # Create the KafkaConsumer connected to the specified brokers. Use the
    # SSLContext that is created with create_ssl_context.
    consumer = KafkaConsumer(
        topic,
        bootstrap_servers=get_kafka_brokers(),
        security_protocol='SSL',
        ssl_context=get_kafka_ssl_context(),
        value_deserializer=value_deserializer
    )

    return consumer
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem when using the kafka python package. I solved it by using an older version of python. Apparently async cannot be used as an argument name in Python 3.7. So either you rename it in the files or use an older version of python. After switchen to Python 3.4 i had no Problems.